# i want to take values from alert view (login id and password) and check if the values for transition using storybords

Tags: ios5

// when i click the button i want an alert view to appear and then entring the login details , if the details are correct then move to next view else not. how to do this ?

// now when i click on the button alert view appears when myButton method ends. how to control the flow ?

```
- (IBAction)myButton:(id)sender
    {
        flag= [self alertview];

        if (flag)
        {
            SecondViewController *svc =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vinay"];
            [svc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
            [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }

-(int)alertview
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login"
                                                    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Enter Login ID and Password:"]
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    flag=1;

    [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
    [alert show];
    return flag;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done to solve this is as below :

1. Need to conforms to the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol in your .h file
2. Then need to implement the delegate method for `UIAlertView`. Method is `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`.
3. Then in method have to track down the button tapped using the button index and to access the text fields of alert view use `NSString *pass = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;` code. (Here the 0 is the first textbox)

Enjoy coding :)